# "The system cannot find the file specified" error running Ant from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ant

I'm trying to run a Python application `word2html` using Apache Ant through a VB project. The following bit of code called for the executable.

```vb
//in loop
If (Not ExecuteProgram("ant", "word2html", True)) Then
            Throw New System.Exception("couldn't run word2html")
        End If

//executeprogram function
Public Function ExecuteProgram(ByVal ExeLoc As String, ByVal ExeArgs As String, ByVal bSynch As Boolean) As Boolean
    'The exefile location is passed in along with a boolean value of whether to 
    'execute the file syncronously or asynchronously
    Try
        Dim MyInstance As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        Dim si As New ProcessStartInfo(ExeLoc, ExeArgs)
        MyInstance.StartInfo = si
        MyInstance.Start()
        If bSynch Then
            'run synch
            MyInstance.WaitForExit()
        End If
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

The code ran successfully a couple weeks ago, but it now fails with the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Vvu.jpg):

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
>
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
>
> at ConsoleApplication1.Hello.ExecuteProgram(String ExeLoc, String ExeArgs, Boolean bSynch)
>
> in
>   C:\Users\shwang\Desktop\svn\trunk\data\data_loading\scripts\data_sheet
>   _scripts\Pipeline\ProcessDatasheetPipeline\Module1.vb:line 349

When I run `ant word2html` from the `cmd` window, it runs successfully.

I suspect it's my working environment that's changed I've checked that the `ANT_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` variable are correct and included in the `PATH` environment variable. What other dependencies should I be checking? I'm currently using Microsoft VB 2010 Express as my IDE.

Comment: [We saw it the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41266801/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix sorry, I added more details.

Comment: They are word for word identical

Comment: I added content, didn't get any responses, so I deleted the old one and reposted. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: The old one was only 2 hours old.  You have to have a little patience, we are not all operating on your time line...and you could have edited your post to update the image although the error should be here in the post not a link to a picture of an error message.  Please read [Ask] and also take the [Tour]

Comment: @Plutonix I tried that but I'm not allowed to because I'm too new. http://imgur.com/o9uUU4I. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ant` is actually a batch script, not an executable. That's why the error message is "The system cannot find the file specified". Windows cannot find an executable named `ant`.

You can use `cmd.exe` with its `/c` option to run the batch script:

```
If (Not ExecuteProgram("cmd.exe", "/c ant word2html", True)) Then
```